# Apache ignite node won't join cluster if server nodes start simultaneously

Tags: ignite

We have a problem with ignite when we start two ignite server nodes at the exact same time. We are currently implementing our own discovery mechanism by extending TcpDiscoveryIpFinderAdapter. The first time the TcpDiscoveryIpFinderAdapter is called neither ignite servers will be able to find the other node (due to the nature of our discovery mechanism). Subsequent invocations does report the other node with a correct IP, yet the ignite nodes will not start to talk to each other.

If we start the servers with some delay, the second server will (on the first attempt) find the other node and join the cluster successfully.

Is there a way to get the two nodes to talk to each other even after both of them initially think they are a cluster of one node?

Comment: No, there is no way to "merge" two clusters of single nodes into a cluster of two nodes. You should fix this at the level of IP finder implementation.

If you need more assistance on this I would recommend you sending this question to Ignite dev list. Also are you sure you need to implement your own IP finder? There are plenty of them available out of the box
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config

Comment: Thank you for the info. We are using Eureka as a service discovery for other services which is why we're implementing our own IP-finder.

Comment: Do you mean this library under Eureka?
https://github.com/Netflix/eureka

If so probably for you it will be enough to use AWS IP finder or JClouds IP finder.
https://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.6/docs/aws-config
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/generic-cloud-configuration

Comment: duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58444937/failed-to-join-apache-ignite-topology-when-multiple-server-pods-starts-at-the-sa/63721700

Comment: for similar issue in k8s see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176143/ignite-readinessprobe