# Ignite ReadinessProbe

Tags: kubernetes, ignite, kubernetes-health-check

Deploying an ignite cluster within Kubernetes, I cam across an issue that prevents cluster members from joining the group. If I use a readinessProbe and a livenessProbe, even with a delay as low as 10 seconds, they nodes never join each other. If I remove those probes, they find each other just fine.

So, my question is: can you use these probes to monitor node health, and if so, what are appropriate settings. On top of that, what would be good, fast health checks for Ignite, anyway?

Comment: I doubt it was ever tested with these probes. Can you provide your configuration and whatever information you have to clarify what you're doing and what is not working as you expect?

Comment: It is a proprietary image built from apacheignite/ignite:2.0.0, so I can't provide too much in the way of specifics, but I can say that it is a cluster of ignite containers that have several caches configured that front a Cassandra ring. The service for discovery is a verbatim copy of the one provided in the documentation, except for some values. I can only assume that the discovery step is interfered with by the fact that the node cannot even see itself because of the readlinessProbe initial delay, so it falls into a weird state.

Comment: Even if I drop the initial delay down to 0 it still interferes.

Comment: the delay of 0 won't change anything I think, the readinessProbe will be `failed` the same way. delay=0 doesn't speed up the probe to be `successful`. It is the probe being `failed` that prevents the `Pod` to be registered as `Endpoint` within the relevant `Service`, I believe

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

[After posting on the ignite mailing list, it looks like StatefulSets are the way to go.  (Thanks Dmitry!)](http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Kubernetes-discovery-with-readinessProbe-td20031.html)

I think I'm going to leave in the below logic to self-heal any segmentation issues although hopefully it won't be triggered often.

**Original answer:**

We are having the same issue and I think we have a workable solution.  The Kubernetes discovery spi lists services as they become ready.

This means that if there are no ready pods at startup time, ignite instances all think that they are the first and create their own grid.

The cluster should be able to self heal if we have a deterministic way to fail pods if they aren't part of an 'authoritative' grid.

In order to do this, we keep a reference to the TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder and use it to periodically check the list of ignite pods.

If the instance is part of a cluster that doesn't contain the alphabetical first ip in the list, we know we have a segmented topology.  Killing the pods that get into that state should cause them to come up again, look at service list and join the correct topology.

Comment: Hi @Bryan Can you explain the approach in detail

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue, using Ignite embedded within a Java spring application.

As you said the `readinessProbe:` on the Kubernetes `Deployment` `spec.template.spec.container` has the side effect to prevent the Kubernetes `Pod`s from being listed on the related Kubernetes `Service` as `Endpoint`s

Trying without any `readinessProbe`, it seems to indeed works better (Ignite nodes are all joinging the same Ignite cluster)

Yet this have the undesired side effect of exposing the Kubernetes `Pod`s when not yet ready, as Spring has not yet fully started ...