# Failed to join Apache Ignite topology when multiple server pods starts at the same time

Tags: kubernetes, ignite

I am currently setting up a stateless Apache Ignite cluster in Kubernetes environment.

During disaster recovery test, I have restart multiple server Ignite nodes simultaneously and intentionally. Those Ignite server nodes was started at about the same time.

Ever since the Ignite server nodes recover, the whole Ignite cluster has gone haywire and the connection between servers and clients are lost and never been recovered.

The following line appears constantly in the Server node log:

```
Failed to wait for partition map exchange [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=572, minorTopVer=0], node=f1f26b7e-5130-423a-b6c0-477ad58437ee]. Dumping pending objects that might be the cause:
```

Edit: 
Added with more log showing nodes are trying to rejoin Ignite topology consistently

```
Added new node to topology: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=91be6833-9884-404b-8b20-afb004ce32a3, addrs=[100.64.32.153, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/100.64.32.153:0, /127.0.0.1:0], discPort=0, order=337, intOrder=212, lastExchangeTime=1571403600207, loc=false, ver=2.7.5#20190603-sha1:be4f2a15, isClient=true]
Topology snapshot [ver=337, locNode=98f9d085, servers=9, clients=78, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=152, offheap=2.3GB, heap=45.0GB]
Local node's value of 'java.net.preferIPv4Stack' system property differs from remote node's (all nodes in topology should have identical value) [locPreferIpV4=true, rmtPreferIpV4=null, locId8=98f9d085, rmtId8=4110272f, rmtAddrs=[securities-1-0-0-6d57b9989b-95wkn/100.64.0.31, /127.0.0.1], rmtNode=ClusterNode [id=4110272f-ca98-4a51-89e3-3478d87ff73e, order=338, addr=[100.64.0.31, 127.0.0.1], daemon=false]]
Added new node to topology: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=4110272f-ca98-4a51-89e3-3478d87ff73e, addrs=[100.64.0.31, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:0, /100.64.0.31:0], discPort=0, order=338, intOrder=213, lastExchangeTime=1571403600394, loc=false, ver=2.7.5#20190603-sha1:be4f2a15, isClient=true]
Topology snapshot [ver=338, locNode=98f9d085, servers=9, clients=79, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=153, offheap=2.3GB, heap=45.0GB]
Completed partition exchange [localNode=98f9d085-933a-435c-a09b-1846cf39c3b1, exchange=GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=284, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_FAILED, evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=f3fb9b23-e3b0-47ab-98da-baf2421fb59a, addrs=[100.64.32.132, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/100.64.32.132:0, /127.0.0.1:0], discPort=0, order=66, intOrder=66, lastExchangeTime=1571377609149, loc=false, ver=2.7.5#20190603-sha1:be4f2a15, isClient=true], done=true], topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=284, minorTopVer=0], durationFromInit=104]
Finished exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=284, minorTopVer=0], crd=true]
Skipping rebalancing (obsolete exchange ID) [top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=284, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_FAILED, node=f3fb9b23-e3b0-47ab-98da-baf2421fb59a]
Started exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=285, minorTopVer=0], mvccCrd=MvccCoordinator [nodeId=98f9d085-933a-435c-a09b-1846cf39c3b1, crdVer=1571377592872, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=117, minorTopVer=0]], mvccCrdChange=false, crd=true, evt=NODE_FAILED, evtNode=b4b25a6f-1d3c-411f-9d81-5593d52e9db1, customEvt=null, allowMerge=true]
Finish exchange future [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=285, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=285, minorTopVer=0], err=null]
Local node's value of 'java.net.preferIPv4Stack' system property differs from remote node's (all nodes in topology should have identical value) [locPreferIpV4=true, rmtPreferIpV4=null, locId8=98f9d085, rmtId8=edc33f38, rmtAddrs=[transfer-1-0-0-846f8bf868-dnfjg/100.64.18.195, /127.0.0.1], rmtNode=ClusterNode [id=edc33f38-9c94-4c4d-a109-be722e918512, order=339, addr=[100.64.18.195, 127.0.0.1], daemon=false]]
Added new node to topology: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=edc33f38-9c94-4c4d-a109-be722e918512, addrs=[100.64.18.195, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:0, /100.64.18.195:0], discPort=0, order=339, intOrder=214, lastExchangeTime=1571403600468, loc=false, ver=2.7.5#20190603-sha1:be4f2a15, isClient=true]
Topology snapshot [ver=339, locNode=98f9d085, servers=9, clients=80, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=155, offheap=2.3GB, heap=46.0GB]
Completed partition exchange [localNode=98f9d085-933a-435c-a09b-1846cf39c3b1, exchange=GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=285, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_FAILED, evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=b4b25a6f-1d3c-411f-9d81-5593d52e9db1, addrs=[100.64.19.98, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:0, /100.64.19.98:0], discPort=0, order=71, intOrder=71, lastExchangeTime=1571377609159, loc=false, ver=2.7.5#20190603-sha1:be4f2a15, isClient=true], done=true], topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=285, minorTopVer=0], durationFromInit=100]
Finished exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=285, minorTopVer=0], crd=true]
Skipping rebalancing (obsolete exchange ID) [top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=285, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_FAILED, node=b4b25a6f-1d3c-411f-9d81-5593d52e9db1]
Started exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=286, minorTopVer=0], mvccCrd=MvccCoordinator [nodeId=98f9d085-933a-435c-a09b-1846cf39c3b1, crdVer=1571377592872, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=117, minorTopVer=0]], mvccCrdChange=false, crd=true, evt=NODE_FAILED, evtNode=c161e542-bad7-4f41-a973-54b6e6e7b555, customEvt=null, allowMerge=true]
Finish exchange future [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=286, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=286, minorTopVer=0], err=null]
Completed partition exchange [localNode=98f9d085-933a-435c-a09b-1846cf39c3b1, exchange=GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=286, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_FAILED, evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=c161e542-bad7-4f41-a973-54b6e6e7b555, addrs=[100.64.17.126, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:0, /100.64.17.126:0], discPort=0, order=38, intOrder=38, lastExchangeTime=1571377608515, loc=false, ver=2.7.5#20190603-sha1:be4f2a15, isClient=true], done=true], topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=286, minorTopVer=0], durationFromInit=20]
Finished exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=286, minorTopVer=0], crd=true]
Skipping rebalancing (obsolete exchange ID) [top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=286, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_FAILED, node=c161e542-bad7-4f41-a973-54b6e6e7b555]
Started exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=287, minorTopVer=0], mvccCrd=MvccCoordinator [nodeId=98f9d085-933a-435c-a09b-1846cf39c3b1, crdVer=1571377592872, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=117, minorTopVer=0]], mvccCrdChange=false, crd=true, evt=NODE_FAILED, evtNode=0c16c5a7-6e3f-4fd4-8618-b6d8d8888af4, customEvt=null, allowMerge=true]
Finish exchange future [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=287, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=287, minorTopVer=0], err=null]
Completed partition exchange [localNode=98f9d085-933a-435c-a09b-1846cf39c3b1, exchange=GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=287, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_FAILED, evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=0c16c5a7-6e3f-4fd4-8618-b6d8d8888af4, addrs=[100.64.34.22, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:0, /100.64.34.22:0], discPort=0, order=25, intOrder=25, lastExchangeTime=1571377607690, loc=false, ver=2.7.5#20190603-sha1:be4f2a15, isClient=true], done=true], topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=287, minorTopVer=0], durationFromInit=52]
Finished exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=287, minorTopVer=0], crd=true]
Skipping rebalancing (obsolete exchange ID) [top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=287, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_FAILED, node=0c16c5a7-6e3f-4fd4-8618-b6d8d8888af4]
Started exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=288, minorTopVer=0], mvccCrd=MvccCoordinator [nodeId=98f9d085-933a-435c-a09b-1846cf39c3b1, crdVer=1571377592872, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=117, minorTopVer=0]], mvccCrdChange=false, crd=true, evt=NODE_FAILED, evtNode=807333d7-0b71-4510-a35d-0ed41e068ac5, customEvt=null, allowMerge=true]
Finish exchange future [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=288, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=288, minorTopVer=0], err=null]
Completed partition exchange [localNode=98f9d085-933a-435c-a09b-1846cf39c3b1, exchange=GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=288, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_FAILED, evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=807333d7-0b71-4510-a35d-0ed41e068ac5, addrs=[100.64.32.231, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:0, /100.64.32.231:0], discPort=0, order=74, intOrder=74, lastExchangeTime=1571377609280, loc=false, ver=2.7.5#20190603-sha1:be4f2a15, isClient=true], done=true], topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=288, minorTopVer=0], durationFromInit=60]
Finished exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=288, minorTopVer=0], crd=true]
```

Comment: Can you provide full logs? Another hint is to search for exceptions in logs upstream.

Comment: @alamar i have added with more long

Comment: Can you paste the complete log file somewhere? It should be under logs/

Comment: for similar issue in kubernetes see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176143/ignite-readinessprobe

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem.
Deploying  each node one by one is the only way to to resove this.,accor.to. As far as my experience with ignite .

Comment: I do not have much control in deciding the deployment or starting time Apache Ignite as I am deploying it as StatefulSet in Kubernetes. Do you know if there is any configuration that I leverage on?

Answer (score 0):

Ignite Mailing list suggests that Kubernetes ReadinessProbe may prevent ignite discovery traffic between pods ...

> Thanks Alex for the response.
>
> Parallel pod management is working.
>
> Earlier I added readiness and liveness probes, with initial delay of
> 180 seconds for the Ignite pods in stateful set because of which no
> traffic was allowed to pods, and hence the discovery failed.
>
> After removing these probes, Parallel pod management is working fine.
>
> Regards, Syed Zaheer Basha

http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Apache-Ignite-Kubernetes-Stateful-deployment-with-parallel-pod-management-td32317.html

Comment: another post http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Not-able-to-join-cluster-with-Zookeeper-based-IP-finder-td9311.html#a9399